# Add a Title and fields in a table got from mysql

Tags: php, pdo, html-table, echo

I have a function that returns a table which is generated from the values that are in a database. 
The function returns a table in this format:

```
 TOTAL  SS      FAI     USER                            RATE
 99     12      87      example.of@mail.com             78
 21     21      0       xxx.zzzzz@domain.com            12
 35     35      0       Unknown address                 16
 60     60      0       002154251                       3
```

---

Here's the function I use:

```
function Table($tab)
{
  echo '<br /><table border ="3">';
  echo '<tr>';

  foreach($tab[0] as $cle=>$val)
  {
    echo "<th>".$cle."</th>";
  }

  echo '</tr>';

  foreach($tab as $cle1=>$line)
  {
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach($line as $cle2=>$val)
    {
      echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
  }

  echo '</table><br />';
}
```

---

I would like to add a column `"TYPE"` and what will be written in it I won't get it from the database.. the values will be defined by typing them. To finally get a table like this:

```
TYPE    TOTAL   SS      FAI     USER                            RATE
KFT     99      12      87      example.of@mail.com             78
VST     21      21      0       xxx.zzzzz@domain.com            12
LSQ     35      35      0       Unknown address                 16
ALE     60      60      0       002154251                       3
```

Comment: Do you want to add `column dynamically` in your table function?

Comment: Just add one more parameter to your function `$userColumn` something & handle it.

Comment: Your question is unclear .Please elaborate

Comment: Then How will you define number of rows for that column? Because other fields are being fetched from DB and it can have so many records.

Comment: No the number of columns is always 4 and for example the first like always corresponds to KFT and the second to VST so on ... 
so the idea is to write KFT, VST, LSQ... etc. so that the person who will see the table will know what each like of the 4 lines corresponds to

Comment: So you mean that there will always be only 4 rows?

Comment: Can you check the answer? Is it what you want?

Comment: yes it's exactly what i want =) many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Table($tab){
    $extraValue = array('KFT','VST','LSQ','ALE');
    echo '<br /><table border ="3">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>TYPE</th>';  // extra column heading
    foreach($tab[0] as $cle=>$val){
        echo "<th>".$cle."</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $i = 0;
    foreach($tab as $cle1=>$line){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>".$extraValue[$i]."</td>";
        foreach($line as $cle2=>$val){
            echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</table><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want an extra column of user input?
If so this may help

```
function Table($tab){
    echo '<br /><table border ="3">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>TYPE</th>';  // extra column heading
    foreach($tab[0] as $cle=>$val){
        echo "<th>".$cle."</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach($tab as $cle1=>$line){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="definedbytypingthem[]" value="" /></td>'; // extra column for user input
        foreach($line as $cle2=>$val){
            echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';}
    echo '</table><br />';
}
```

update to include adding another column to the data

```
function addcolumn(&$tab, $new_values){
    foreach($tab as $cle1=>$line){
        if(is_array($new_values[$cle1])) {
            $tab[$cle1]=array_merge($line, $new_values[$cle1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Where $new_values is an array of similar format to $tab.
Using array_merge will allow for several columns to be added at a time
BUT the size of both arrays should be the same

So:
$data[0]['TOTAL']
$data[0]['SS']
$data[0]['FAI']
$data[0]['USER']
$data[0]['RATE']

and
$newdata[0]['TYPE']

`addcolumn($data, $newdata);`

will be merged the into $data to give:-
$data[0]['TOTAL']
$data[0]['SS']
$data[0]['FAI']
$data[0]['USER']
$data[0]['RATE']
$data[0]['TYPE']

Comment: thank you that is almost what i need i think my question wasn't clear, what i meant by typing them is typing them in the code the values in the column TYPE will be always the same

Comment: +1 you thought and implemented in form of `textbox`. But then How `Kirk ERW` will store those value in back to DB?.

Comment: Do yo mean that you want to supply an extra array of values for TYPE? if not, please explain the link between rows and the values of TYPE

Comment: No no i don't want to store them in the DB !! xD what i meant is not that the user type the values in the columns,  i meant that i'll define them in the code

Comment: You only want to specify column name as an extra parameter to function  and then you want to fetch that column and it's corresponding value from DB for that column, right?

Comment: if you look at my question there's a first table which is generated by the function using at FETCH_ASSOC... what i want is to add a type column when it prints the table like in the second table